# Get string from code

Tags: jquery, contains

I have the following code:

```
<a href="mailto:info@domain.com" class="liens" title="eMail">eMail</a>
<br>
<span class="siteweb_fiches"><a href="http://www.domain.com" target="_blank" class="liens">Website</a><br></span>
<span class="siteweb_fiches"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/Item" target="_blank" class="liens" title="Facebook">Facebook</a><br></span>
<span class="siteweb_fiches"><a href="http://twitter.com/Item" target="_blank" class="liens" title="Twitter">Twitter</a></span>
```

I need to get some information like the email address, the website, the Facebook and the Twitter page.

1. I can't change this code.
2. I can't work with .liens because, there's a lot of in the page.

-

What I tried:

- eMail: `$( "a:contains('eMail')" ).text();`
- wsite: `$( "a:contains('Website')" ).text();`
- faceB: `$( "a:contains('Facebook')" ).text();`
- twitter: `$( "a:contains('Twitter')" ).text();`

Comment: Just because there's a lot of `.leins` in the page, doesn't mean you can't use that class to select the element. Most likely there's some unique feature of the hierarchy that will allow it.

Comment: Was just to prevent `.eq(0)` answer for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get href value of `<a>` using this

```
var a = $( "a:contains('eMail')" ).attr('href')
var b = $( "a:contains('Website')" ).attr('href')
var c = $( "a:contains('Facebook')" ).attr('href')
var d = $( "a:contains('Twitter')" ).attr('href')

console.log(a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + d)
```

Comment: It is always helpful to provide some explanation along with your code. Just saying "use this" isn't really a high-quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var email = $("a.liens[title=eMail]").prop("href");

var website = $("a.liens[title=eMail]").siblings(".siteweb_fiches:eq(0)").find("a").prop("href");

var facebook = $("a.liens[title=eMail]").siblings(".siteweb_fiches:eq(1)").find("a").prop("href");

var twitter = $("a.liens[title=eMail]").siblings(".siteweb_fiches:eq(2)").find("a").prop("href");
```

I am getting **href** value, you can get text by using `text()` if that is required.

### [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ysmxrryp/)

Comment: Differences between the Vitorino Fernandes answer ?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
var email, website, facebook, twitter;
$('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf('eMail')>-1){
        email=$(this).prop('href');
    }
    else if($(this).text().indexOf('Website')>-1){
        website=$(this).prop('href');
    }
    else if($(this).text().indexOf('Facebook')>-1){
        facebook=$(this).prop('href');
    }
    else if($(this).text().indexOf('Twitter')>-1){
        twitter=$(this).prop('href');
    }
});
```